# Rewriting this database access query to circumvent 'DISTINCT ON' error, in Django

Tags: python, django, performance, postgresql, sqlite

I have two very simple models:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])
```

In the bid to get the latest `publicreply` for each `link` object, I tried this: `latest_replies = Publicreply.objects.filter(answer_to_id__in=link_ids).order_by('answer_to', 'submitted_on').distinct('answer_to')` where `link_ids` is a list of all `link` objects I needed in this particular case.

Problem is, I get a **DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend**. I'm on SQLite locally, Postgres in production. What's a way to re-write this query such that I get the same result? Note that I don't want to run a database query under a FOR loop - I've profiled that and the results are very unsavory. Is there a single query to get the job done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just take care of the `distinct` in memory.

```
replies_by_link = {}
replies = Publicreply.objects.filter(answer_to_id__in=link_ids).order_by('answer_to', 'submitted_on')

for reply in replies:
    if reply.answer_to_id not in replies_by_link:
        replies_by_link[reply.answer_to_id] = reply
```

and then you can access all the replies via `replies_by_link.values()`.